# TB not wrapping when adding font

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I want to place a block of text at 120,60 that should wrap when the text gets too long. Here is my code:

```
^XA
^FO120,60^TB,300,200^FD1 puff pa morgonen, 1 puff pa kvallen. Inandas. Kortison
^FS
^XZ
```

The text is too small however, so I add ^ADN,20,12 like this:

```
^XA
^FO120,60^TB,300,200^ADN,20,12^FD1 puff pa morgonen, 1 puff pa kvallen. Inandas. Kortison
^FS
^XZ
```

After that, the text no longer wraps. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the order of the commands:

```
^XA
^FO120,60^ADN,20,12^TB,300,200^FD1 puff pa morgonen, 1 puff pa kvallen. Inandas. Kortison.
^FS
^XZ
```